# Как записать данные структуры в файл?

Tags: c++, файлы

Имеется часть кода:

```
struct St
{
    char Name[30];
    int math;
    int phys;
    int inf;
    int chem;
    int dateOfBirth;
    int group;
    double ball;
} Students;

void addStudent() {
    f1 = fopen("list.txt", "w");
    cout << "Enter the Name of student: ";
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    gets_s(Students.Name, 29);
    cout << "Enter the math ball: ";
    cin >> Students.math;
    cout << "Enter the informatics ball: ";
    cin >> Students.inf;
    cout << "Enter the physics ball: ";
    cin >> Students.phys;
    cout << "Enter the chemistry ball: ";
    cin >> Students.chem;
    cout << "Enter the date of birth: ";
    cin >> Students.dateOfBirth;
    cout << "Enter the group of student: ";
    cin >> Students.group;
    cout << "Enter the average ball: ";
    cin >> Students.ball;
    fwrite(&Students, 1, sizeof(Students), f1);
    fclose(f1);
}
```

Задача - считать данные с консоли, записать их в переменные структуры и позже записать данные структуры в файл. Сделал таким образом, однако в файле получаю:

```
Sergei юююююююююююююююююююююю   



   Р  >ж
       $@
```

Думаю, что ошибка в `fwrite()`, но не до конца понимаю, как в нее правильно записать параметры, ибо в структуре переменные разных типов

Answer (score 1):

Да нет, у вас тип - нормальный plain old data, так что все, что, возможно, надо сделать - добавить букву `b` в режиме работы файла, если вы в Windows (в Linux вроде разницы нет? Точно не уверен...), чтоб это был именно **бинарный** файл.

Ваш вариант записи просто сбрасывает в файл **все**, что есть в структуре. Только вот и читать его потом нужно через `fread` в такую же структуру. Ясно, что "глазами" вы видите частично мусор (пустое место, оставшееся в поле имени) и бинарные представления чисел.

Если же вам нужно именно для человека - ну, открывайте `ofstream` и пишите с помощью `<<`, например. Или в файл, открытый через `fopen`, с помощью `fprintf`. Только тогда смотрите, пишите так, чтоб потом могли прочесть - например, имя на отдельной строке, чтоб не спуталось при чтении с числами.

Comment: Наверное, еще и выравнивание структуры следует включить, а то 30 не кратно 4...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Неважно; лишь бы запись и чтение выполнялись с одним выравниванием. Если это в одной программе - то данное условие выполнено автоматом...